# Comma Separating Ordinary Prepositional Phrase Following Object

Tags: commas

I was playing a board-game last night with my friends and stumbled on this sentence in the rule book:

> Each Mine Region your Dwarves occupy is worth 1 bonus Victory Coin, at
>   the end of your turn.

I thought this was a really strange way to use a comma and probably a mistake, but the rule book had so many other similar examples:

> Place a Troll's Lair in each region you occupy, to increase its
>   defense by 1.

I mentioned this to a friend during the game. They assured me that it was correct and told me to read *Stunk and White*. I didn't want to contradict him, because I needed him in an alliance against an army of skeleton warriors.

Is this comma usage okay? Is there a name for it?

Comment: As far as I'm aware there are many linguists who see Strunk & White as a pointless and prescriptivist anachronism that has no place in Modern English. There is no reason for the commas in the example sentences.

Comment: +1 for "I didn't want to contradict him, because I needed him in an alliance against an army of skeleton warriors."  The commas definitely aren't necessary, but I wouldn't consider them incorrect.

Comment: 'Stunk and White'. Is the pun intended? 'Strunk and White' often makes very authoritative-sounding pronouncements, not only on grammar (where you're usually better consulting a better-researched work) but also on style, where there are usually different opinions (eg on comma placement). If I wished to 'set off' the prepositional phrase or to-infinitival here, I'd go with parentheses rather than a comma. One can't say the commas are wrong, and sometimes they clarify long sentences.